# WildFly: jboss-cli's add module creates a wrong folder

Tags: wildfly, jboss-cli

I am taking my *very first steps* with WildFly application server. I want to create a database driver.

I had a look at https://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/installing_oracle_jdbc_driver_on on how to do it manually. And now I want to do it by `jboss-cli.sh`. I read about these commands e. g. [here](https://www.techgalery.com/2019/09/add-mysql-driver-to-wildfly.html) and [here](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jbossas/jboss-script/installing-a-jboss-as-7-module-using-the-cli/).

So I am typing...

```
wildfly-26.0.0.Final/bin$ ./jboss-cli.sh -c
[standalone@localhost:9990 /] module add --name=com.oracle --resources=/home/user/Downloads/ojdbc8.jar --dependencies=javax.api,javax.transaction.api
```

The command is going to be executed without error.

I would expect it to

1. create the module-subfolders (step 2 in the linked tutorial by Adam Bien)
2. copy the JAR file to the newly created folder (step 3)
3. create the `module.xml` file (step 4)
4. maybe even to add the necessary `<driver />` tag in the `standalone.xml` (do not know if that should be part of the `add module` command?) (step 5)

Basically it does *a lot of* that, but different than I expect.

It creates the subfolder in a wrong(?) location. It is not created in `[WILDFLY_HOME]/modules/system/layers/base/com/oracle/main` like it is decribed by Adam Bien but it is created `[WILDFLY_HOME]/modules/com/oracle/main`. The JAR file is correctly copied, the module.xml file is created but the folder seems to be wrong. And the standalone.xml is not altered at all.

If I start the web management console I do not see the driver next to the default H2 one.

So my question is what am I doing wrong with the command so that the folder is created in the correcy localtion? Or does this *work as designed* and the location is not that relevant and I am making other mistakes that it does not show in management console nor in standalone.xml?

---

By the way, I also tried to change the command `module add --name=system.layers.base.com.oracle ...`. Now the folder was correct, but in the module.xml the name of the module was also `system.layers.base.com.oracle`.

I tested with WildFly 26.0.0 and WildFly-preview 26.0.0 under Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should not be created in `modules/system/lasers/base`. That is for components provided by the container. Having the module off the root `$JBOSS_HOME/modules` directory is correct.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Does that mean the mentioned tutorial as well as https://ralph.blog.imixs.com/2016/10/22/wildfly-install-postgresql-jdbc-driver-as-a-module/, https://www.intforcesoftware.com/installing-oracle-jdbc-driver-on-wildfly-jboss/ and https://medium.com/@hasnat.saeed/install-and-configure-mysql-jdbc-driver-on-jboss-wildfly-e751a3be60d3 (all links from the first result page of a web search) are all wrong?

Comment: IMO they are not correct yes. It's a common misconception that modules should be created there because that's where the other modules are. However, both really work. It's just preferred to put them in the main `modules` directory for user modules.